# How to inherit variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function Singer(g) {
  this.genre = g;
  this.rock = function() {
    console.log("ROCK");
  }
}

Singer.prototype.sing = function() {
  console.log(this.genre);
}

function metalSinger() {

}

metalSinger.prototype = Singer.prototype

var james = new metalSinger();
console.log(james.sing())
```

The metalSinger object only inherits the prototype function of object Singer. How can I inherit the variables of Singer (this.genre) and also the function (this.rock) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class pattern with inheritance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

```
function Singer(g) {
   this.genre = g;
   this.rock = function() {
   console.log("ROCK");
 }
}

Singer.prototype.sing = function() {
  console.log(this.genre);
}

function MetalSinger(g) {
  Singer.call(this, g);
}

var ms = new MetalSinger("foo");
console.log(ms.rock());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by calling the parent constructor function inside the child constructor like this:

```js
function Singer(g) {
  this.genre = g;
  this.rock = function() {
    console.log("ROCK");
  }
}

Singer.prototype.sing = function() {
  console.log(this.genre);
}

function metalSinger() {
  Singer.call(this, 'metal');
}

metalSinger.prototype = Object.create(Singer.prototype);

var james = new metalSinger();
james.sing();
```

This way before constructing the child object, parent constructor will be called first to initialise the object.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I inherit the variables of Singer (this.genre) and also the function (this.rock) ?

Basically like this:

```
Singer.call(this, genre);
```

By doing so, you first call `Singer` in context of `metalSinger` which adds its (Singer's) properties to `this` object of `metalSinger`. Also it is better to create new object through `Object.create()` and put all the functions in Prototype.

```js
function Singer(g) {
    this.genre = g;
}
Singer.prototype.sing = function() {
    console.log(this.genre);
}
Singer.prototype.rock = function() {
    console.log("ROCK");
}

function metalSinger(g) {
    Singer.call(this, g);
}

metalSinger.prototype = Object.create(Singer.prototype);

var james = new metalSinger("metal");
james.sing(); // "metal"
james.rock(); // "ROCK"
```